# get chars in certain positions of a string

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Hello there misters and ladies!

This is what I have atm.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h> 

const int numerolinhas = 8;
const char ficheirodec='t';
const char ficheirobin = 'b';

int primeiracoordenada(char opcao1) {
    int numero;
    numero = ((int)(opcao1))-64;
    if(numero<1 || numero >8){
        printf("Error: Invalid coordinate.\n");
        exit(1);
        }else{
    return numero;
    }
}


int segundacoordenada(char opcao2){
    int numero;
    if(opcao2 == '1' || opcao2 == '2' || opcao2 == '3' || opcao2 == '4' || opcao2 == '5' || opcao2 == '6' ||opcao2 == '7' || opcao2 == '8'){
        numero = (int)(opcao2) - 48; /* Converter para numero de 1 a 8 na tabela ascii*/
        numero = (numero -1) * 4;
        return numero;

    }else{
        printf("Error: Invalid coordinate.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

int terceiracoordenada(char opcao3){

    int numero;
    if(opcao3 == '1' || opcao3 == '2' || opcao3 == '3'){
        numero = (int)(opcao3)-48;  /* Converter para numero de 1 a 3 na tabela ascii*/
        numero -= 1;
        return numero;
    }else{
        printf("Error: Invalid coordinate.\n");
    exit(1);
    }
}

void leituracartao(char opcao1, char opcao2, char opcao3){
    int i = 0;
    char linha[8][35];
    FILE *ficheiro;
    ficheiro = fopen("texto.txt","r");
    if (ficheiro == NULL){
            printf("Error: could not open file.");
            exit(1);
    }
        while(fgets(linha[i], 35, ficheiro)){
        i++;
        }
    fclose(ficheiro);
       for(i = 0; i <=numerolinhas; ++i)
    {
        if(primeiracoordenada(opcao1) == i){
            if(linha[primeiracoordenada(opcao1)-1][segundacoordenada(opcao2)+terceiracoordenada(opcao3)]>4 && linha[primeiracoordenada(opcao1)-1][segundacoordenada(opcao2)+terceiracoordenada(opcao3)]<58){
            printf("%c ", linha[primeiracoordenada(opcao1)-1][segundacoordenada(opcao2)+terceiracoordenada(opcao3)]);
            }else{
                printf("Error: File is corrupted.");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}   

void leituracartaob(char opcao1, char opcao2, char opcao3){
    int i = 0;
    char linha[8][25]; /* 24 *8 faz o total de os 192 bytes e de seguida acrescatamos +1 byete para por  o char '\0' em cada linha*/
    FILE *ficheiro;
    ficheiro = fopen("argv[1],","br");
        if (ficheiro == NULL){
            printf("Error: could not open file.");
            exit(1);
        }
        while(fgets(linha[i], 35, ficheiro)){
        i++;
        }
    fclose(ficheiro);
       for(i = 0; i <=numerolinhas; ++i)
    {
        if(primeiracoordenada(opcao1) == i){
            if(linha[primeiracoordenada(opcao1)-1][segundacoordenada(opcao2)+terceiracoordenada(opcao3)]>47 && linha[primeiracoordenada(opcao1)-1][segundacoordenada(opcao2)+terceiracoordenada(opcao3)]<58){
            printf("%c ", linha[primeiracoordenada(opcao1)-1][segundacoordenada(opcao2)+terceiracoordenada(opcao3)]);
            }else{
                printf("Error: File is corrupted.");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}       

int main(int arg, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *ficheiro;
    char opcao1 =0;
    char opcao2 = 0;
    char opcao3 = 0;
    char opcao4 =0;
    char opcao5 = 0;
    char opcao6 = 0;
    char opcao7 =0;
    char opcao8 = 0;
    char opcao9 = 0;
    char pedido[14];

    if (arg != 3 ) {
        printf("Error: Invalid arguments.");
        exit(1);
        }
    if(*argv[2]== ficheirodec){
        ficheiro = fopen(argv[1],"r");
        if (ficheiro == NULL){
            printf("Error: could not open file.");
            exit(1);
        }
    scanf("%[^\n]s", pedido);
    opcao1 = pedido[0];
    opcao2 = pedido[1];
    opcao3 = pedido[2];
    opcao4 = pedido[4];
    opcao5 = pedido[5];
    opcao6 = pedido[6];
    opcao7 = pedido[8];
    opcao8 = pedido[9];
    opcao9 = pedido[10];
    leituracartao(opcao1, opcao2, opcao3);
    leituracartao(opcao4,opcao5,opcao6);
    leituracartao(opcao7,opcao8,opcao9);
    }else{
        if(*argv[2]== ficheirobin){
        ficheiro = fopen(argv[1],"br");
        if (ficheiro == NULL){
            printf("Error: could not open file.");
            exit(1);
        }
            scanf("%[^\n]", pedido);
            opcao1 = pedido[0];
            opcao2 = pedido[1];
            opcao3 = pedido[2];
            opcao4 = pedido[4];
            opcao5 = pedido[5];
            opcao6 = pedido[6];
            opcao7 = pedido[8];
            opcao8 = pedido[9];
            opcao9 = pedido[10];
            leituracartaob(opcao1, opcao2, opcao3);
            leituracartaob(opcao4,opcao5,opcao6);
            leituracartaob(opcao7,opcao8,opcao9);
            }
    }
    fclose(ficheiro);
    return 0;
}
```

This program is supposed to ask for to arguments before opening (in my example, something like

```
argv[1] = "texto.txt"
argv[2] = 't'
```

Then it will read a text file. In that text file, I have 8 lines like a matrix. The file have this kind of configuration:

```
042 811 268 930 893 582 838 307 
(new line of file here)
972 019 257 399 054 070 433 138 
(new line of file here)
189 083 331 047 303 922 470 475 
(new line of file here)
667 974 152 342 046 800 560 362 
(new line of file here)
```

(and a little more, a total of 8 lines, every single one like that but with random numbers).

on my console, I can use the following command:

> "./projecto3 texto.txt t"

and then put some input, something like this

> "A11 A12 A13"

and I would get the output with the `texto.txt` coordinates (A means first line, 1 means first word, 1 means first letter of the word).

The program is working all right, I can print the coordinates I want to print. But there is a segmentation fault somehere in that big, fat code. Diferent OS give me diferent results, I can have the program working without any problem on mine but in another OS, I see the segmentation fault.

I am trying to found ways/tools to find out where the problem here is, but I am a newbie and I already struggled hardcore to get to this point with all my code.

Any kind of help, code changes, just the line where the problem is would be apreciate. Make sure, when you answer back, that I am a newbie with c programming.

Comment: It's a pretty big code blob yes. Also, it's pretty hard to understand when all identifiers are in non-english. You should use a debugger to find exactly where the segfault occurs, and then remove as much code as possible while still reproducing the problem, in other words, create a [mre]

Comment: Suspect: `for(i = 0; i <=numerolinhas; ++i)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ficheiro is uninitialized.

I ran [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) on it and got this:

```
~/work/scratch $ cppcheck main.c
Checking main.c ...
main.c:159:12: error: Uninitialized variable: ficheiro [uninitvar]
    fclose(ficheiro);
           ^
```